# Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

I have a `<div>` with `id="modal"` generated dynamically with the jQuery `load()` method:

```
$(".show-product").click(function(){

    $("#modal").load($(this).attr("href"), function(e){

        $(".details").click(function(){
```

I had to put the code in the click event of the class '. detail' within this code, because if what I had was not running. I have the code in both places, since I also use it outside of the modal, being doubled.

Something similar happens to me with a table that I build dynamically, thanks to an example that I saw here, Stack Overflow. It does not capture the click event, the window darkens as when it opens the modal, but it does not call the url or load. This code:

```
$.ajax({
    url : form,
    type: "POST",
    data : postData,
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $("#dynamicTable>tbody>tr").remove();
        var x = [];
        $.each(dataSet, function(i, item) {
            x.push('<tr><td><a href="/product/' + item.product.id + '" class="details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">' + item.product.name + '</a></td>');
            x.push('<td>' + item.product.name + '</td></tr>');
        });
        $("#dynamicTable>tbody").html(x.join(""));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Not product found!');
    }
});
event.preventDefault()
```

I think that in both cases events is not working because they are loaded dynamically. I was looking for here and on Google and try to make changes but it does not work without having to duplicate code (in the event `$(document).ready` and at each event that loads data dynamic, the modal window and load table).

Changes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //$(".show-product").click(function(){
    $(".show-product").on("click", function(e){

        $("#modal").load($(this).attr("href"), function(e){

            //$('.details').click(function(e){
            // ........
        });
    });
    // Added
    $(".details").on("click", function(e){
        ..........
        ..........
    });
});
```

With these changes still do not work, only works in pages with static content, when I get to have the content dynamic (modal, table dynamics and others) does not working events.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Try change $(".details").on("click", to $("#dynamicTable").on("click", ".details", fun...

Comment: @Alexander Seems very obfuscated, as the mine of duplicating the code in both events :-S. Your code could reuse to capture the event from the non-modal page? Thanks for your reply ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegating the event to `body` fixes the issue since it avoids attaching handlers directly to the dynamically-generated elements:

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".details", function(e){
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use jquery `on()` for events on dynamically created elements.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Is it like what I have mentioned above?

To my worked me by putting the code as I have answered myself, seems not to good use of the event. on. Check your link and so I hope learn more ;-)